# vim plugins for improved workflow - any like this?

Tags: ide

Are there any plugins to check code quality real-time when programming in vim? similar to tools like ReSharper(I imagine, I have only seen them used and never tried them myself) I would be interested in any plugins for refactoring, real-time format detection, code smell detection etc. It's not imperative but it would be nice! Would be nice to check for abbreviations and words not in my project glossary too, to ensure readability.

I am currently particularly interested in c# for the unity game engine, but I prefer my tools to be as generic and widely applicable as possible! If possible, I would like all my tools to be open source, easily extended, well documented, as generic as possible. I want my tools to be available for all my needs for years to come, regardless of which operating system or programming language etc.

But that's obviously asking quite a lot. But at the very least it would have to satisfy my current requirements, to be useful with C#.

Comment: Your question is currently too broad, do you have any language in mind ? have you tried anything right now ?

Comment: Updated my question. I have not tried anything within vim for refactoring. I have tried youcompleteme and syntastic plugins, among others that don't seem as worthwhile mentioning. I have also tried tagbar and such.

Comment: Since you're asking for a plugin recommendation, please follow [Software Recommendations' guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) in framing your question.

Answer (score 3):

I've got a [generic refactoring plugin](https://github.com/LucHermitte/vim-refactor) for Vim. It's mainly tuned for the languages I work with (C++, VimL, ...). It can be extended to C#, however there already exist [refactoring "things" for C#](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Vim_as_a_refactoring_tool_and_some_examples_in_C_sharp).

At this time, it relies on ctags. Someday I'd like to look into what is possible with clang (I know there is https://github.com/realincubus/vim-clang-refactor, but it doesn't seem to permit to automatically apply naming policies). BTW, the extract method/function refactoring doesn't work as well as I'd like to.

Regarding code smells detection, it requires the use and integration of other tools. It won't be very easy to have something generic as all languages have different code smells and good practices. syntastic plugin may be a first step in that direction. Note, that in lh-cpp I have a few syntax highlights that detect things like `if (foo = 42)`.